# Draw custom map tile images (.pngs) on top of Google Map - Android

Tags: java, android, sdk, maps

I have png images of map tiles over parts of the UK and i want to draw them on top of the google maps view, I have everytyhing set up, just want to be able to draw the tile images now.

My main class extends 'MapActivity', can i add a canvas function to draw them?

ALso, I only obviously need to draw the tiles that are in view on the phone while the tiles out of view should not be drawn.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an Overlay to the MapView, that will get you a canvas to draw on. See http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html

Comment: I got some overlay items drawing, how can i draw the map tiles i have over the areas they should be? Add the map tiles as overlay items ?

Comment: Use Projection (get it by doing getProjection() on your MapView) to figure out where to draw your tiles from the lat/long coordinates.