# How to draw custom map tiles without OSMDroid apis in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, customization, tiles

I went through lots of searching the web which shows how to draw custom tiles on top of Google Maps using OSMDroid apis. I have my custom tiles png files ready to use.

But I am looking for a way which will help me to draw custom tiles on top of default google map tiles. I also found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842782/draw-custom-map-tile-images-pngs-on-top-of-google-map-android) which says to use overlays for the same.

Now I am confused between the overlays and custom tiles; please correct me if I am wrong, as I think overlays are the one we use as markers on top of a map.

How can I draw custom tiles *without* using OSMDroid in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An overlay is just a layer, it can contain pins or tiles.

You need an overlay to display your tiles.

OSMDroid is the only current way I know for displaying tiles over Google Maps.

You can see how to use it there:
https://groups.google.com/group/osmdroid/browse_thread/thread/1e2219b8e2d28edb/6c1ed8e13520fce1